# Is there any explanation about Selim Bradley's true form?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

After the defeat of Selim Bradley (aka Homunculus Pride), his true form is revealed to be a tiny baby in a fetal position.

This makes me wonder, is Selim Bradley's true form is actually an aborted fetus, found later by The Father and given new life as Homunculus Pride?

This will explain a lot about his psychology (ex: Unconditional obedience towards his Father).

Comment: The production of a homunculi in the stories of alchemists is literally the production of a miniature human (esp. body) by alchemical means.  The Selim Bradley body is a mask.  The 1st true form is a recreation of the dwarf in the flask himself (which shows he is playing god). The real form is what a homunculi should be. Bringing aborted fetuses into this is needlessly reaching for the macabre.  If a human body is an ingredient for the production of the homunculi, it is by definition no longer a homunculi.  It is more fitting say that by recreating God's greatest work, Father has become god.

Answer (score 1):

I think that none of the original forms of the homunculi are given an explanation.

- Lust has the body of women that can change her fingers to needle
  things.
- Wrath is a mortal homunculus that has a human body.
- Sloth has that big giant kind of body.
- Envy has that green monster thing as the original form that he
  disguises to a normal human body.

Only Gluttony can be given a reasonable explanation for his original body. He is the failed gate of truth and hence has a false gate in his stomach.

You can argue Envy has that green monster body since he is a compilation of many human souls but that is true for all the homunculi, so we can't take that as an explanation.

Also, I went through the WIKI and couldn't find anything on this.

I also think the fetus body remained in the end because Pride was removed (killed) from the body and only that fetus remained symbolically telling that the monster has been removed and only a pure form of the being (baby) remains(even though the baby is a homunculus).

Answer (score -1):

All of their natural forms represent the sin they are. Pride is a child, arrogant as many children are, envy is a green ugly monster representing jealousy, sloth is big and powerful held back by his own laziness, lust is a sexual icon, gluttony is fat etc

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.